# Making a value of an object to null in a object list in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I have a list of object stored in a state called `itemsToUpload`. There's a button to upload the list of objects to a database. The following is an object in the list.

```
{
type:"Fiat",
 model:"500",
 color:"white",
imgUrl="https://latestlyhunt.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Fiat-made-a-%E2%80%98Hey-Google-car.jpg"
};
```

When sending the data to the database, I want to make the `imgUrl` to null.

The following code is how I set the `imgUrl` to null.

```
const submitHandler =async()=>{

setitemsToUpload((items)=>
        items.map((item)=>({
          ...item,
          imgUrl:null
        })))

    const response =await axios.post("api url",itemsToUpload)
console.log(response )

}
```

After making the `imgUrl` to null,`itemsToUpload` state changes but the data sending to the API states that `imgUrl` is not null

What is the issue here?

Comment: The issue is clearly outside of the code snippets you provided. Could you please provide a link to codesendbox where issue is reproduced?

Comment: Can you please share code where you calling the API and sending data.

Comment: @Alexl. _"...provide a link to codesendbox where issue is reproduced?"_ - You're "required" to add a [mcve] _in the question itself_ and not on a third-party site that might break or not be accessible for everyone (code-only or preferable as a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) which also work with React)

Answer (score 1):

[Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) doesn't modify the array, it creates a new array with the returns value, so you need to assign the result of your map to the array

```js
const items = [
{
type:"Fiat",
 model:"500",
 color:"white",
imgUrl:"https://latestlyhunt.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Fiat-made-a-%E2%80%98Hey-Google-car.jpg"
}
]


const modifiedItems = items.map((item)=>({
  ...item,
  imgUrl:null
}))

console.log(items)
console.log(modifiedItems)
```

Comment: True, since question is related to React we can assume that `setitemsToUpload` updates React state

Answer (score 0):

The code is working here. So I'm not sure if the problem belongs with this part.

```js
const array = [{
type:"Fiat",
 model:"500",
 color:"white",
imgUrl:"https://latestlyhunt.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Fiat-made-a-%E2%80%98Hey-Google-car.jpg"
},
{
type:"Fiat",
 model:"500",
 color:"white",
imgUrl:"https://latestlyhunt.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Fiat-made-a-%E2%80%98Hey-Google-car.jpg"
},
{
type:"Fiat",
 model:"500",
 color:"white",
imgUrl:"https://latestlyhunt.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Fiat-made-a-%E2%80%98Hey-Google-car.jpg"
}];

console.log(array);

const clearIt = array => {
  return array.map(item => {
  item.imgUrl = null
  return item;
  });
};

const newArray = clearIt(array);

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: wha solves the issue here is that you extract the `Array.map` in a function and use it's return value, op discard the return value of the map and expect his array to be altered

Answer (score 0):

In your code `setitemsToUpload` does not immediately mutates the `itemsToUpload` but rather tells React to schedule a state update and rerender, while `submitHandler` continues to run and calls `axios.post` before `itemsToUpload` is updated.

Try to refactor it like this:

```
const submitHandler = async () => {
    const newItemsToUpload = items.map((item) => ({
        ...item,
        imgUrl: null
    }))

    setitemsToUpload((items) => newItemsToUpload)

    const response = await axios.post("api url", newItemsToUpload)
    console.log(response)
}
```